# Precondition SSDs

Tags: ssd, benchmarking

Are there still good reasons to "preconditioning" your SSD, especially before doing benchmark?
And if so, why?
Today we have better SSDs and almost all system-configurations support TRIM.

Comment: Found this note in regards to read benchmark and new disks: "..reads might won't make it all the way to the nand if the mapping table is empty" ([spinics.net](https://www.spinics.net/lists/fio/msg05203.html))

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The professional way of benchmarking an SSD is described.

Before a benchmark is done, if not brand new, the SSD has to be purged to
put it into a state that is as close as possible to fresh out of the box.
This is usually done by a manufacturer utility that can TRIM/erase the
whole disk.

The second step is to apply a workload repeatedly to the SSD,
while monitoring its performance, until performance results get into stable
state where the repetitions don’t fluctuate by too much.

When the SSD is in a stable condition, the benchmark should be run immediately,
not giving time to the firmware to do any garbage collection that will affect
future results.

Comment: Are you saying it's all about a full-disk-trim, which I always do and can be done by `blkdiscard -v /dev/xx` on linux).
It was my understanding there were more to it, like writing the whole disk one or multiple times with data for some reason?

Comment: I'm saying that after TRIM the state of the disk is abnormal and a benchmark would be unrealistic. The above procedure aims for a realistic state.